# How to iterate data and display as per their belonging group name in php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am selecting data from database and displaying in table but now i want to display all data as per their agent name and balance amt of their agent which is associated on other table.

```
Customer Table

    id agent_id
    1    5
    2    5
    3    6

    Balance table

    id agent_id bal_amt
    1    5       25000
    2    6       7000
```

But i want to display like below format, means i want to display agent name in row and rest data related with agent name in columns

**Expected result**

```
Agentname  category  subcategory  balance
ABC                               25000
            Ring     plastic
            Node     fibre
            test     rassi
XYZ                              7000
            sofa     rod
            mate     code
```

**Below is my code**

```
     <?php  
                            $finalArray = [];
                            foreach ($customerlist as $user) { print_r($user);exit;
                                $finalArray[$user['agent']['name']][] = $user;
                            }
                            foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value) {
                        ?>

    <tr>
                            <td colspan="7"><?php echo $key; ?></td>
                            <td colspan="2">25000</td>
                        </tr> 
                        <?php foreach ($value as $user) { ?>
                         <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                        <td><?php echo $user['product']['name'];  ?></td>
<?php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, need to first group all entries for agents in one array and then traverse through those to get desired output. Try this code:

```
<?php
$finalArray = [];
foreach ($customerlist as $user) {
    $finalArray[$user['agent']['name']][] = $user;
}

foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td> 
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>  
    <?php foreach ($value as $user) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
            <td><?php echo $user['product']['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['subproduct']['name']; ?></td>
        </tr>  
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Here first `tr` will be print `Agent Name` and other `tr` in inner `foreach` loop will print to entries of that agent.

Comment: Note that in CakePHP 3.x, `$customerlist` will most likely be a collection, so one could do `$customerlist->groupBy('agent.name') as $group => $users`. Also I'd suggest looking into [**`rowgroup` scopes**](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/), which is ment for cases like this, which also improves accessibility.

Comment: yes its correct as per my expected result but i want to display balance amount as well in front of agent which is associated with agent_id in balance table.so plz help me how to bind this balance amount with agent name.

Comment: i change my expected result and pasted data which i am getting on wall.